# How does matchmaking in the Arena work?

Tags: hearthstone

When playing in Arena mode in Hearthstone, how is your opponent determined? Are you only ever matched up against someone with the same or similar record as you? For example, if you win your first game then in your next game you would play someone who is also playing their second game after winning their first.

Or maybe it's completely random?

Comment: As far as I know it's completely random, since Blizzard thinks that the (more or less) random deck you have to use in the arena evens out the skill. Gonna write an answer if I have confirmation on this, or maybe I'm just remembering it wrong...

Comment: I thought there was something said about how you are matched up with players in the arena with approximately the same win-to-loss ratio.  But that may have been changed.

Answer (score 11):

According to [Hearthstonecast](http://hearthstonecast.com/2013/07/26/livestream-changes-the-forge-becomes-the-arena) from July 2013

> Matches in “The Arena” mode follow a match making protocol to ensure that players of similar play strength (meaning players with comparable win/loss records) are matched up against each other. Obviously, such a system would improve over time and not be as reliable in the early stages of Hearthstone going live.

The link to HearthstoneCast is broken right now, but this has been confirmed by Blizzard devs on twitter several times. The arena matchmaking algorithm [does not look at your previous arena or constructed history](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/718440547665321984) and it [does not consider the card quality](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/685525869914230784) of the deck you have drafted.

Current (unconfirmed, fan-based) thinking is each match you are matched to someone with the same Arena score as you, so for your first game you are playing someone who is also on 0-0, if you then lose, your next game will be against someone who has also just lost one game.

I would guess as well that matchmaking is something that will be being fine-tuned for a while.

Comment: I don't care what Blizzard say that's all bull 4 matches now i have been put against the worst possible match in all account's 6 games lost between play and arena 4 of them arena and still getting people that are fare superior players than my self

Comment: @Martin: Yes, Blizzard has decided that you specifically will receive bad matchups and give favorable matchups to those opponents you played against. 4 whole arena matches? 2 whole play matches? That's less than an hour of gameplay.

Comment: @AndrewS no there matching system dose not work well at all the best thing they could have done to try and balance it is deck dust counting get the dust value for the cards of a desk sum them try to match make via that aswell as your plaid stats

Answer (score -2):

It works very much like a slot machine.

The dial spins around several times before finally matching you with a Worthy Opponent. Thankfully, this process never seems to land on opponents like Nose and Mouther Breather, Cheater McCheaterson, or Grand Master.